# Convert Image URL to HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage, httppostedfilebase

I have an image URL and I want to convert it to HttpPostedFileBase in order to delete the image from the Azure Blob.

For example, I have the following image URL

> http://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg

How can I convert it to HttpPostedFileBase in MVC controller?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an image stored in Azure Blob Storage and you have the URL for that (something like `http://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/image.png`). You want to delete that image from Blob Storage in an MVC controller. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri ya, you are correct.

Comment: Do you have access to storage account name and key?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have those access account name and key. but the question is how can I convert the image url to HttpPostedFileBase in Controller?

Comment: You don't have to :). Let me provide an answer to your question in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete a blob in your storage account, you would need to use Azure Storage SDK (which is essentially a wrapper over Azure Storage REST API). You mentioned that you have the URL of the blob and have access to storage account and key. Using the code like something below, you can delete a blob from your storage account in your MVC controller.

```
        var credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var cloudBlob = new CloudBlob(new Uri(blobUrl), credentials);
        cloudBlob.DeleteIfExists();
```

The code above assumes that you provide `blobUrl` as a parameter to your MVC controller.